# How do I exclude dependencies from Flutter submodule to merge with native app?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I have a native android project with a lot of submodules and custom flutter library that added as a submodule as well and dependency set up as described here: [option B](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup#option-b---depend-on-the-modules-source-code) with `settings.gradle`

the issue is that some submodules are uses exoplayer, and flutter library uses it as well. so, while building I got a lot of dependency issue:

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.spherical.Projection$SubMesh found in modules jetified-exoplayer-core-2.10.1-runtime (com.amazon.android:exoplayer-core:2.10.1) and jetified-exoplayer-core-2.10.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.10.1)
```

it seems force does not working in this case:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.10.1'
}
```

how can I exclude exoplayer from flutter lib?

Only option I found for now is to build .arr and exclude from here, but it not working for me as flutter library also is in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
implementation project(':flutter')
```

with

```
implementation(project(":flutter")) {
        exclude module: 'exoplayer-core'
        exclude module: 'exoplayer-hls'
        exclude module: 'exoplayer-dash'
        exclude module: 'exoplayer-smoothstreaming'
    }
```

"(" and ")" around "project" is required